# How to display the results of a for-loop in one dialogwindow?

Tags: java

I'm currently learning from a book about Java. I want the output of my program to display several numbers in just one JOptionPane.showMessageDialog-window. So, the program asks for the lowest and the highest number from the user, then shows every 7th number between those.

```
 public void count1() {
     int min, max;
     min = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("lowest number"));
     max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("highest number"));
     for (int i = min; i <= max; i += 7) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i + " ");   
     } 

 }
```

My problem is that this block of code produces several message windows displaying all numbers, but I want all those numbers in the same message window. I've searched here on Stackoverflow and seen other people with the same question but the answers have been suggesting "append" and "stringbuilder" which the book hasn't covered yet. Surely, there must be a more simple way? Thanks.

Comment: Just construct a `String` using a `StringBuffer` (thread safe) and display that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
String result = "";
for (int i = min; i <= max; i += 7) {
        result += i + " \n";
     }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm and was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to concatenate everything into a String. For instance :

```
public void count1() {
     int min, max;
     String elt = new String("");
     min = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("lowest number"));
     max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("highest number"));
     for (int i = min; i <= max; i += 7) {
         elt = elt + i + " ";
     } 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, elt);   
 }
```

But at each time you use the "+" sign or String.concat("") way, you'll create a new object, and store this object in the heap. So if you want to think about the performance, it's better to use StringBuilder instead of String, for instance :

```
public void count1() {
     int min, max;
     StringBuilder elt = new StringBuilder("");
     min = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("lowest number"));
     max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("highest number"));
     for (int i = min; i <= max; i += 7) {
         elt.append(i).append(" ");
     } 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, elt.toString());   
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I will keep this in mind for the future. So many friendly and active people on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud have a variable that save the message you want to show, and that is composed inside the loop.

And then you just open the dialog.

This is an example of a trivial solution:

```
public void count1() {
    int min, max;
    min = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("lowest number"));
    max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("highest number"));
    String buff = "";
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i += 7) {
        buff += i + " ";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, buff);
}
```

Here is the example of the proper solution:

```
public void count1() {
    int min, max;
    min = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("lowest number"));
    max = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("highest number"));
    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i += 7) {
        buff.append(i).append(" ");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, buff.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but the problem is that I haven't been learning about append and Stringbuilder yet. Those are covered in the next chapters. This should be doable without those, according to the author.

Comment: If you use the `+` operator on a `String` you're doing append which is just a `StringBuffer` underneath.

Comment: _The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method._

Comment: @wulfgarpro I know that in the last version of jvm the use of *+* versus StringBuilder/StringBuffer it's just a matter of readability of the code in most of the use cases.

Answer (score -1):

Store your in an **arrayList** and the you can show the list in **alert dialogue**.

Comment: This solution is not false I think. The definition of the method accepts showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message) and probably do a toString() on the message variable. The default behaviour of toString on ArrayList is to show your list of values as : [value1, value2, value3 .....].